# Getting No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version' from jar-with-dependencies shaded jar

Tags: akka, maven-shade-plugin, jar-with-dependencies

I've used the maven-shade-plugin given in the [akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html) and it creates a shaded jar as evidenced by the following output from maven build:

```
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.2:shade (default) @ remoting.example ---
[INFO] Including com.typesafe.akka:akka-remote_2.11:jar:2.4.8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.typesafe.akka:akka-protobuf_2.11:jar:2.4.8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.6.Final in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.uncommons.maths:uncommons-maths:jar:1.2.2a in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:jar:2.4.8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.11:jar:0.7.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing /home/dschulze/src/java/akka/remoting.example/target/remoting.example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with /home/dschulze/src/java/akka/remoting.example/target/remoting.example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: /home/dschulze/src/java/akka/remoting.example/dependency-reduced-pom.xml
```

When I run the jar-with-dependencies I still get

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'
```

I've also tried several other  that I've found on various posts on the web, but none of them create a jar-with-dependencies that works.  How can I create a jar-with-dependencies that uses akka?

Comment: Tried with `-Dakka.version`?

Comment: Adding `-Dakka.version` gives `No configuration setting found for key 'akka.actor.provider'`.  So it looks like it just move the problem to the next property.  Is your approach documented anywhere?  How many properties am I going to have to override on the command line like this?

Comment: See my answer. I suspect you need to provide an application.conf on the classpath that'll provide the minimum configuration.

Comment: Did my answer help? If so can you be a good citizen and accept?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation regarding using a [jar or bundle](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#When_using_JarJar__OneJar__Assembly_or_any_jar-bundler):

> Akka's configuration approach relies heavily on the notion of every module/jar having its own reference.conf file, all of these will be discovered by the configuration and loaded. Unfortunately this also means that if you put/merge multiple jars into the same jar, you need to merge all the reference.confs as well. Otherwise all defaults will be lost and Akka will not function.

You can provide a custom `application.conf` as described [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#Custom_application_conf):

```
akka {

  # Loggers to register at boot time (akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger logs
  # to STDOUT)
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]

  # Log level used by the configured loggers (see "loggers") as soon
  # as they have been started; before that, see "stdout-loglevel"
  # Options: OFF, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG
  loglevel = "DEBUG"

  # Log level for the very basic logger activated during ActorSystem startup.
  # This logger prints the log messages to stdout (System.out).
  # Options: OFF, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG
  stdout-loglevel = "DEBUG"

  # Filter of log events that is used by the LoggingAdapter before
  # publishing log events to the eventStream.
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"

  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"

    default-dispatcher {
      # Throughput for default Dispatcher, set to 1 for as fair as possible
      throughput = 10
    }
  }

  remote {
    # The port clients should connect to. Default is 2552.
    netty.tcp.port = 4711
  }
}
```

This covers the `akka.actor.provider` setting it's complaining about, amongst others.

Answer (score 0):

In you are using the plugin settings provided by Akka, there should be a new jar available that ends in -allinone.jar.  This jar is the shaded jar.